# PHP Regex regular expression including space

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to identify if the user has typed someone else's username if the typed an at symbol (@) before it, much like on twitter. My function can recognise the @ symbol and the username after it, but it includes the a spacebar after it (if there was one).

Here's my regex stuff

```
/@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(\s|\Z)/
```

So let's say that a user typed

```
@testificate blah blah blah
```

My function would select the following (between the | symbols)

```
|@testificate |blah blah blah
```

When what I actually want is for it to select

```
|@testificate| blah blah blah
```

It includes the space afterwards and that's not what I want. Is there a better way to do this? I'm turning the @ tags into links with a preg_replace, can anyone help me out? Thanks

Comment: Can you show the preg_replace statement?

Comment: Be careful. This regular expression will erroneously match portions of e-mail addresses. You probably want to ensure that the character preceding the "@" is a nonword (`\W`) character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why you add `(\s|\Z)` ?

```
\s space
\Z End of subject or newline at end

Regex: /@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/
```

#### Edit:

**davidchambers**'s suggestion

```
Shorter Regex: /@(\w)+/
```

Comment: Actually, I can't remember why.. must have been stuck in a train of thought that, looking back, doesn't make much sense now. Well that's awkward, but thanks for your answer! I'll mark it as *the* answer when I can :)

Comment: `/@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/` can be further simplified: `/@(\w+)/`. :)